# POST data attributes on click using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following html:

```
<div class="actor_container span-3 column" data-url="http://www.spotlight.com/5094-1276-6177" data-age-min="31" data-age-max="40" data-height="180" data-weight="72" data-gender="male" data-eye="green">
....
</div>
```

Is it possible to POST each data attribute when the user clicks the image, and then in another file I can use $_GET to retrieve them?

So for example, something like this:

```
$('.actor_container').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).data("url"),
                ...rest of code goes here...
            });
        }); //on
```

Then in my PHP file, use something like:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
```

**UPDATE**
From answer below, here is my JS code (I've posted the full on click function so you can see):

```
$('.actor_container').on("click", function (e) {
            $('.loading_overlay').show();
            $('#actor_data').hide();
            $('#actor_data_container').css('top','0'); 
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/plugins/nial-customizations/front-end/actor-profile.php?url=" + $(this).data("url"),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
                    // append all data
                    $('#actor_data').html(data);
                    $('#actor_data').show();
                    $('.loading_overlay').hide();
                }
            });


           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({ 
                    "age-min" : $(this).data("age-min"), 
                    "age-max" : $(this).data("age-max") 
                }),
            });

});
```

and then in my PHP file I have:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

which returns

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: Sure is! Post what you have so far.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Marcus not very much, but added it in

Comment: @Hackerman did you mean to post a blank jsfiddle?

Comment: If i remember, if you use ajax with POST method, you only retrive them with $_POST varaible in the other php file.

Comment: why do you need to use $_GET, when you can access it by $_POST?

Comment: @Harikrishnan because I don't really understand them. Happy to use $_POST if I know how to do it

Comment: @SamSkirrow $_POST are the global array same as $_GET excpet $_GET gets value from url and $_POST gets value from the request

Comment: @Harikrishnanthanks, this makes sense. Going to go and do a bit of reading up on this too

Comment: @SamSkirrow check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to serialize your data :

```
$('.actor_container').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var length_data = Object.keys($(this).data()).length;
    var data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length_data; i++) {
      var str = Object.keys($(this).data())[i]
      data.push({ name : str, value : $(this).attr('data-'+str) })
    }
    $.post("your_page.php", data);
})
```

And on your php site, you can access to data with :

```
    $_POST['url']
    $_POST['age-min']
    $_POST['weight']
    ...
```

For try the serialization, here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL1pccnh/)

**UPDATE**

Mix your 2 ajax call :

```
$('.actor_container').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading_overlay').show();
    $('#actor_data').hide();
    $('#actor_data_container').css('top','0'); 
    var length_data = Object.keys($(this).data()).length;
    var data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length_data; i++) {
      var str = Object.keys($(this).data())[i]
      data.push({ name : str, value : $(this).attr('data-'+str) })
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/plugins/nial-customizations/front-end/actor-profile.php",
      data : data,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {
        var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
        // append all data
        $('#actor_data').html(data);
        $('#actor_data').show();
        $('.loading_overlay').hide();

    });
```

Comment: This is a great answer, however it's not working for me. In my php file, when I use echo $_POST['age-min']; it returns nothing, and in my console I get a server 500 error for the php page

Comment: I believe so, it's the exact same url as in my AJAX call in my question - and that works

Comment: What i don't understand is : why are you doing 2 ajax call ? and the second has not url setting.. If it's the same url, do everything on 1 call. If it's different url, you have not specified it on the second call.

Comment: Yes that's a very good point. And then I use $_GET['age-min'] etc in my php file correct?

Comment: I edited my answer, but i can't try it, tell me. And yes, if you send your data correctly, you can retrieve it with $_GET['age-min']

Comment: Yep, couple of syntax errors but nothing that isn't an easy fix. Other than that it seems to work. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to POST each data attribute when the user clicks the image, and then in another file I can use $_GET to retrieve them?

No.

If you POST them in one request then the data appears in that request (in `$_POST` if you use a form encoding).

If you want `$_GET` to have the data in it when you make some later request, then you need to put the data in the query string for that request (and it probably makes POSTing them with Ajax redundant).

You could POST them with Ajax and then store them somewhere (such as in a session) and then read them back from wherever you stored them instead of using `$_GET` in the later request.

Comment: OK, I think that makes sense. So is it possible to store these data attributes in a session variable when the user clicks on it?

Comment: Yes. That is one of the approaches I suggested.

Comment: Awesome. Do you have any example code to accompany your answer?

Comment: PHP session tutorials are two a penny. The world doesn't need another one.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you how to use the $_POST method with jquery.

**Your example**

```
$('.actor_container').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({ "url" : $(this).data("url"), "second_key" : variable_or_value }),
                ...rest of code goes here...
            });
        });
```

In the above example in the data i gave a `key` which is `url` and given the value. You can access the value from `PHP` by `$_POST['url']` . The second can be accessed by `$_POST['second_key']`

Comment: OK I see, so presummably I can add as many variables under "data ({ }); and then retrieve them each with $_POST['data variable']

Comment: @SamSkirrow yes by seperating with comma. I will update with that

Comment: This does make sense, but when I have implemented it it's not working for me - updated in my question